# How do I sort list of numerical value dictionaries?

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I have two files with 6000 numerical values.I am giving just first 15 values of both.

```
base.txt
2.900000e+03
2.900000e+03
2.900000e+03
2.900000e+03
2.900000e+03
2.900000e+03
2.900000e+03
2.900000e+03
2.900000e+03
2.900000e+03
2.900000e+03
2.900000e+03
2.900000e+03
2.900000e+03
2.900000e+03
```

new2.txt

```
    0
  100
  200
    1
  101
  201
    2
  102
  202
    3
  103
  203
    4
  104
  204
```

I want to create a new list from the base.txt  values(velocities) that would correspond to ascending order of second file.(0,1,2,3,4,5,..)
My code so far

```
import itertools
from operator import itemgetter

vel = [line.strip() for line in open("base.txt", 'r')]
ind = [line.strip() for line in open("new2.txt", 'r')]

print type(vel)
print type(ind)

adict = dict(itertools.izip(ind,vel))

newlist = sorted(adict, key=itemgetter(ind))
```

My idea was to read files as lists,create dictionary and then try to sort out the values,but this code is not working.
I got this

```
<type 'list'>
<type 'list'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "m1.py", line 11, in <module>
    newlist = sorted(adict, key=itemgetter(ind))
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not list
```

The files are here
http://pastebin.com/he1RuSnv

http://pastebin.com/VfXZB4W3

When I try solution of CPanda,I got

```
2.900000e+03 0
2.900000e+03 1
2.900000e+03 10
2.900000e+03 100
2.900000e+03 1000
2.900000e+03 1001
2.900000e+03 1002
2.900000e+03 1003
2.900000e+03 1004
2.900000e+03 1005
2.900000e+03 1006
2.900000e+03 1007
2.900000e+03 1008
2.900000e+03 1009
2.900000e+03 101
2.900000e+03 1010
2.900000e+03 1011
2.900000e+03 1012
```

This is not what I want,Iwant second index to go 0,1,2,3,4,5 and so on...

Comment: Why is not working? what is the expected output and what do you get instead, i.e. any error?

Comment: @Francesco Have edited my post,take a look!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve the error, your last line, the one with `sorted` should be

```
newlist = [el[1] for el in sorted(adict.items())]
```

Sorted returns a list of key value tuples from the dict.

Then with the list comprehension you extract the ordered values into your `newlist`

You can also merge the last two lines into one:

```
newlist = [el[1] for el in sorted(itertools.izip(ind,vel))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a dictionary or an associative array in this case is not what you are looking for.  A dictionary is orderless and should not be used when order matters.

I would use a different data structure like the one mentioned here.

[Sort a Python dictionary by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/sort-a-python-dictionary-by-value)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import itertools

with open("base.txt") as fv, open("new2.txt", 'r') as fi:
    vel = (line.strip() for line in fv)
    ind = (int(line.strip()) for line in fi)
    z = itertools.izip(ind, vel) # sort according to ind
    # itertools.izip(vel, ind) # sort according to vel
    for i, v in sorted(z):
        print v,i

# interactive session
l1 = ['2.900000e+03',
      '2.900000e+03',
      '2.900000e+03',
      '2.900000e+03',
      '2.900000e+03',
      '2.900000e+03',
      '2.900000e+03',
      '2.900000e+03',
      '2.900000e+03',
      '2.900000e+03',
      '2.900000e+03',
      '2.900000e+03',
      '2.900000e+03',
      '2.900000e+03',
      '2.900000e+03'] # list(vel)
l2 = [0, 100, 200, 1, 101, 201, 2, 102, 202, 3, 103, 203, 4, 104, 204] # list(ind)
# result
2.900000e+03 0
2.900000e+03 1
2.900000e+03 2
2.900000e+03 3
2.900000e+03 4
2.900000e+03 100
2.900000e+03 101
2.900000e+03 102
2.900000e+03 103
2.900000e+03 104
2.900000e+03 200
2.900000e+03 201
2.900000e+03 202
2.900000e+03 203
2.900000e+03 204
```

- Use generator expressions instead of lists for memory efficiency and speed.
- Use context managers to automatically `close` open files

Please comment if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: @C Panda No this does not work.I will paste my files so you can try yourself.

Comment: you want to sort the second one and according to that u want to arrange the first one, right?

Comment: Yes,the second one should go from 0 then ascending and I want to arrange the first one.

Comment: @RichardRublev that was a small bug.